# iOS SDK - Affecting neighboring objects using animation?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

Lets say I have a subview with some text fields and labels inside of it.

Then I try to animate it like so:

```
[self.testView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.testView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 548)];
}];
```

I noticed that testView is animated, but the elements inside stay wherever theyre positioned.
Is there any way to make this behave more like jquery/html where when I expand an element, it will push another element down the page etc?  Or does this need to all be programmatically done.

I am trying to create accordion menu type functionality..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto layout may be the answer for your issue. It is a rather complex topic but for a starting I suggest you go through the tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

The other solution is to animate and position all your views programmatically.